# SSL connection mysql symfony 7

Tags: symfony, ssl, doctrine

After an upgradeto symfony 7, i'm not able to connect to my azure mysql database with SSL.

Before upgrade, in symfony 5.4 this connections was OK.

My 5.4 doctrine.yaml looks like and works fine:

```
    dbal:
        server_version: '8.0'
        driver: pdo_mysql
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
        options:
            !php/const:PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA: '%env(resolve:CA_CERT)%'
```

With symfony 7 !php/const:PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA can't be used

What is the correct config ?

Thanks in advance